# 2D Array Problem

Tags: algorithms

I have a grid of size $N \times N$.

Initially all cell's of grid are dead. I have four types of operations.

1. All of row $i$ is set to $1$ then all cells are convert into lives cells of row $i$
2. All of row $i$ is set to $0$ then all cells are convert into dead cells of row $i$
3. All of column $i$ is set to $1$ then all cells are convert into lives cells of column $i$
4. All of column $i$ is set to $1$ then all cells are convert into lives cells of column $i$

There are two queries which I want to know:

1. row $i$ find all the live cells in the row $i$
2. col $i$ find all the live cells in the column $i$

Actually I came to a solution.

I make a two array one for ROW query and second for column query
or Row updation I update row array in $O(1)$ and for column operation I update the array of ROW in $O(n)$ and same for Column query array
same for Column query array.

i get a answer in $O(1)$. i want to know is there any way to do it better solution.

For example:

```
000
000
000
```

after row $1$ $1$ operation

```
111 <- row 1
000
000
```

after col $2$ $1$ operation

```
111
010
010
```

after row $3$ $0$ operation

```
111
010
000
```

Comment: 1. All caps on the Internet is interpreted as shouting. Please don't shout. 2. You don't need to indent your paragraphs; it makes your text display as preformatted code.

Comment: When you say "find all the live cells", do you mean simply to find _how many_ live cells there are? Actually finding all of them cannot possibly be done in $O(1)$ time since that is not even enough to print the result.

Comment: is it possible in O(logn) time

Comment: I see this is the February [CodeChef Challenge](http://www.codechef.com/FEB13/problems/MBOARD). It is not okay to try to use MSE to gain a leg up on ongoing competitions - correspondingly this question will be locked until the end of the competition (in two days)